# Sharpening blade, move away from self or pull towards me?

Tags: sharpening

Most instruction books I get included with sharpening stones say to push the blade away from myself as though I was trying to slice off a thin layer of the stone. In other words, the instruction books recommend moving the blade towards edge side.

In "The Razor's Edge Book of Sharpening", however, the author, Jovanovitch, says that this is wrong and that the blade should be pulled across the stone away from the edge. He says that pushing the edge towards the stone will cause grit to flow over both sides of the edge and this will cause dullness.

Which advice is better?

Comment: Apparently both, otherwise seven million people do it wrong now. [Sharpening Knife on a Whetstone with Master Sushi Chef Hiro Terada.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t39rhQs6Hqc) "with a 1000 grit Masahiro whetstone, and then further polishes his knife with a Kikuichi 6000 grit wet stone."

Comment: More than 7 million... if you were to only push the blade away from you then you would need to switch to your off-hand for the off-side of the blade, most assuredly wrecking your sharpening angle (except for the truly ambidextrous...).

Comment: that extra grit could also sharpen it, it's all a numbers game on the molecular level.